# How to return all records having only integer values in a specific column?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to return all records where a certain column has only integer values.

For example,

```
parent_id        category_id
    1                43656
    2               aabc6gn
    3                 1123
    4                aaxxyy
```

The result should be -

```
parent_id        category_id
    1                43656
    3                 1123
```

Comment: Are we talking about databases here? Also, which vendor?

Comment: You cannot have different datatypes in the same column. BigQuery is schema specific.

Comment: @JackDaniel I interpret the OP as meaning that `category_id` is a text column, some of whose values are all-integer text values.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen In that case, your solution works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
select *
from yourTable
where not regexp_contains(category_id, r'[^\d]')
```

if to applied to sample data from your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`SAFE_CAST(column_name as INT64)`

This function safely cast records and it returns a NULL value when it's not possible to apply the casting rule.

Use this trick to filter out the records that are not integer in a STRING column:

```
SELECT parent_id, category_id
FROM table
WHERE SAFE_CAST(category_id AS INT64) is not NULL;
```

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#safe_casting

Answer (score 0):

Use `REGEXP_MATCH` here:

```
SELECT parent_id, category_id
FROM yourTable
WHERE REGEXP_MATCH(category_id, r'^[0-9]+$');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by attempting to convert to an integer:

```
where safe.convert(category_id as int64) is not null
```

I interpret your question as saying that the value can be converted to an integer, not that every digit is an integer.

If the latter, I would simply use:

```
where regexp_contains(category_id, '^[0-9]+$')
```